# open with plist file in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, plist

I want to open plist file using windows phone 7 and apparently he couldn't understand the extension of the file ,because when i change it from file.plist to file.xml it works !! But I need it to work on plist extension.

I am using this code to open it:

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri(@"/myproject;component/cdp/document-category-info.plist", 
    UriKind.Relative)); 
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream); 
string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a file from Isolated Storage or is your plist embedded within one of your assemblies as a resource or included in your app's setup?

Your code above constructs an isolated storage file object, but never uses it and then tries to read the named resource from your EXE.

Comment: i am sorry i didn't mean to put that line ,the file is on the project i just copied and pasted in a cdp folder in the solution